# Qt : Segfault when zooming on QGraphicsDropShadowEffect

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyside

I've been experiencing a really weird bug recently:

Often when I zoom too much on a `QGraphicsItem` (using `scale` on the view containing it) that has a `QGraphicsDropShadowEffect` on it, my app closes with a `segmentation fault (core dumped)` error.

What's weird is that:

1. I use Python (with the PySide binding)
2. If I remove the `QGraphicsDropShadowEffect`, the bug disappears

I also had to remove the `QGraphicsDropShadowEffect` on a relatively big item because it got the app *so* slow to the point it became irresponsive when I zoomed a bit too much.

Do anyone know how I could fix this ?

Comment: Here I am 8 years later facing the same issue.. is there really no explanation?

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not help but when I encountered this the only thing that helped was reinstalling/updating pyside. I thought the fixed that bug a while back however.

Comment: Where did you install it from? (I got it from the Ubuntu repository, It seems to be the latest version : 1.1.2)

Comment: I was installing it from their website(windows) when it happened to me.